# How do I grant an OAuth2Permission to a Service Principal that isn't an App Registration?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a Service Principal that was created by a system-assigned managed identity. It doesn't appear in the Portal because it isn't an App Registration. I know it exists though because I can see it in Powershell by running:

```
($ServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "MyService") | Write-Output
```

App Registrations can be granted App Permissions by linking them to Application Roles exposed by the App Registration for the API. I can't do that in the portal for my managed identity, so how?

Answer (score 1):

`New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment` is the tool I needed.

When invoking it, one must pass:

- the ObjectId of the Service Principal (this doesn't appear in the portal but can be found with `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`)
- the ID of the role from the appRoles section of the audience service's manifest
- the ObjectId of the audience Service Principal (not the ObjectId of the App Registration)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you already answered your question yourself.

Are you sure, that you can't see the Service Principal? Under "Enterprise applications" is a drop list. Can you see your Service Principal if you select "All Applications"?

[image]